# PublishProgress not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I did hours of research and reading about these things, but I still can't figure out the problem with my code:
I have a View with a Button and two TextViews.
On click of the button, a procedure is called, that downloads a file, analyses it and prints the outcome of the calculation to one of the TextViews. The other one just takes the Status, if the infinite calculation is started or not.
So much for theory. 
Practically nearly everything works, except of the part where publishProgress should print the calculation output to the TextView. (The calculation is started again, but no text appears in the TextView.)

I hope anybody can help me out of this.

Here is my code:

```
package com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;



public class AIM_start extends AppCompatActivity {
    static String downURL = "http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-magnetometer-primary.txt";
    static String errPatt = "-1.00e+05";
    public TextView status;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button stopButton;
    public TextView output;
    start_AIM calc = new start_AIM();
    private boolean func = false;

    public static String strengthArr[] = new String[4];

    static {
        strengthArr[0] = "90,110,90,110";
        strengthArr[1] = "50,89,111,150";
        strengthArr[2] = "0,49,151,200";
        strengthArr[3] = "-50,-1,201,-250";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aim_start);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusView);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_output);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_aim);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener (){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!func) {
                    func = true;
                    startButton.setText("Stop AIM");
                    status.setText("AIM-Started");
                    calc = new start_AIM();
                    calc.execute();
                } else {
                    func = false;
                    startButton.setText("Start AIM");
                    calc.cancel(false);
                    status.setText("AIM-Stopped");
                }
            }
        });
    }



    class start_AIM extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        public String doInBackground(String... params){
            while (!this.isCancelled()) {

                System.out.println("before publishProgress Update");
                //publishProgress("Calculation Started");

                dataImport dI;
                try {
                    dI = new dataImport(downURL);
                    String calcData;
                    calcData = dI.download();

                    System.out.println(calcData);
                    preAnalysis pA;
                    pA = new preAnalysis(calcData);
                    boolean dateOk;
                    dateOk = pA.preanalyse();
                    if (dateOk) {
                        System.out.println("Data Date is okay");
                        //call last line downloader
                        dI = new dataImport(downURL);
                        String lastLine;
                        lastLine = dI.downloadLast();
                        if (!lastLine.contains(errPatt)) {
                            //data is ok
                            System.out.println("Current data is okay");
                            System.out.println("Current data: " + lastLine);
                            System.out.println("Starting analysis");

                            analyse an = new analyse(lastLine);
                            int strength;
                            strength = an.analyseData();
                            if (strength != -1) {
                                System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
                                //outputText(Integer.toString(strength));
                                publishProgress(Integer.toString(strength));
                                //return Integer.toString(strength);


                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Strength not found");
                                //send signal for out of scope to output
                                publishProgress("-1");
                                //return "-1";
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Current data is not okay");
                            publishProgress("Current data is not okay");
                            //send signal for satellite down to output
                            publishProgress("-1");
                            //return "-1";
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Data Date not okay");
                        publishProgress("Data Date not okay");
                        //send signal for satellite down to output
                        publishProgress("-1");
                        //return "-1";
                    }


                    //catch statements
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    System.out.println("MalformedUrlException for dI allocation");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException in dI alloc");

                    //check inet conn/send satellite down to output
                    return "Connection expired";
                }
                //return "ERROR";
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        protected void outputText(String result) {
            output.setText(result);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            Log.d("MyApp", "finished");
            outputText(result);
        }


        protected void onPreExecute(String text) {
            status.setText(text);
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String text) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(text);
            Log.d("MyApp", "onProgressUpdate called");
            status.setText(text);

        }


        final class dataImport {
            private String downData = "";
            private URL url = null;
            private String lastLine = "";

            dataImport(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
                URL allocUrl = new URL(url);
                this.url = allocUrl;
            }

            String download() throws IOException {
                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));

                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    downData += line;
                    lastLine = line;
                }
                return downData;
            }

            String downloadLast() throws IOException {
                this.download();
                return lastLine;
            }
        }

        class preAnalysis{
            private String data;
            private String dataDate;
            private String sDate;
            private Calendar dateToCheck = Calendar.getInstance();
            private Calendar timeToCheck = Calendar.getInstance();

            preAnalysis(String data){
                this.data = data;
            }

            boolean preanalyse(){
                dataDate = this.getDataDate(data);
                sDate = this.getDataTime(dataDate);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HHmm");


                //TODO make date convert right
                try {
                    dateToCheck.setTime(formatter.parse(dataDate));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
                try {
                    timeToCheck.setTime(formatter.parse(sDate));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //convert from UT
                Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, -2);
                currentTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
                //currentTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.HOUR -2, Calendar.MINUTE -5);

                System.out.println("dateToCheck: " + dateToCheck + "; current Date: " + currentDate);
                System.out.println("timeToCheck: " + timeToCheck + "; current Time: " + currentTime);
                System.out.println("timeToCheck Time:" + timeToCheck.HOUR + ":" + timeToCheck.MINUTE);
                System.out.println("time checked: " + currentTime.HOUR + ":" + currentTime.MINUTE);
                if(dateToCheck.YEAR == currentDate.YEAR && dateToCheck.MONTH == currentDate.MONTH &&
                        dateToCheck.DAY_OF_MONTH == currentDate.DAY_OF_MONTH &&
                        timeToCheck.HOUR == currentTime.HOUR && timeToCheck.MINUTE == currentTime.MINUTE){      //&& !timeToCheck.before(currentTime.getTime())
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            private String getDataDate(final String data){
                return data.substring(35,51);
            }

            private String getDataTime(final String dataDate){
                return dataDate.substring(12);
            }
        }


        final class analyse{
            private String data;
            private String[] splittedData = new String[4];
            private Double[] splittedStrength = new Double[4];
            analyse(String data){
                this.data = data;
            }

            int analyseData(){
                data = this.getCalcData();
                this.splitCalcData();
                String temp = splittedData[3];
                double tempSplit = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                int counter = 0;
                for (String i : strengthArr){
                    this.splitStrength(i);
                    if ((tempSplit >= splittedStrength[0] &&
                            tempSplit <= splittedStrength[1]) ||
                            (tempSplit >= splittedStrength[2] &&
                                    tempSplit <= splittedStrength[3])){
                        return counter;
                    }
                    counter += 1;
                }

                return -1;
            }

            private void splitStrength(String strength){
                String[] temp;
                temp = strength.split(",");
                for(int b = 0; b < temp.length; b++){
                    splittedStrength[b] = Double.parseDouble(temp[b]);
                }
            }


            private String getCalcData(){
                return data.substring(37);
            }

            private void splitCalcData(){
                splittedData[0] = data.substring(0,8);
                splittedData[1] = data.substring(13,21);
                splittedData[2] = data.substring(25,33);
                splittedData[3] = data.substring(35);
            }
        }


        abstract class dataOut{
            void out(){

            }
        }

        final class lblOut extends AppCompatActivity {
            void outputToLbl(String value){
                final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textViewToChange.setText(value);
            }
        }

        final class bluetoothOut extends dataOut{
            void bluetoothOut(){

            }
        }

        final class audioOut extends dataOut {
            void audioOut() {

            }
        }






    } //fin start aim


} //fin main
```

Comment: You have not override publishProgress method in asy task which increase your progress bar.

Comment: If I write @Override before my onPublishProgress it gives me the error
does not override method of superclass

Comment: @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

Comment: Where would I add that?

Comment: inside class start_AIM.

Comment: Okay.. I have updated the code.
I added the Override Method...
Works without errors;
but there still is no output on the textview...

Comment: setText in onProgressUpdate mrethod.

Comment: You are the best thank you for your help... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have missed method `onProgressUpdate` in your `start_AIM extends AsyncTask`

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         doSomething(progress[0]);
}
```

Docs are here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have moved the protected void onProgressUpdate(){

Comment: Try to add  procedure to your class AIM_start and call it from onProgressUpdate